# Python data subtraction and plotting

Tags: python, arrays, list, matplotlib

I have two data sets f and g. Each are a different length. I need to plot the difference of f and g against time t. It won't subtract, however, because it givesValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,11944) (2,23600)". I'm also not sure how to make the variable t the same length as x because it keeps telling me "ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension". Here's the code so far:

```
f=np.loadtxt('Single Small Angle 1.txt',unpack=True,skiprows=2)
g=np.loadtxt('Single Small Angle 3.txt',unpack=True,skiprows=2)

x=f-g
t=[]

plt.plot(t,x)
#plt.xlabel("${\Theta}$ [rad]")
#plt.ylabel("${\Omega}$ [rad/s]")
#plt.title("Small Angle Approximation Phase Space")
plt.show()
```

I then need to find the exponential fit for x vs. t which I don't know how to do either.

Comment: Try with `x = f-g[:,:11944]`

Comment: That works however I'm still unsure what to make t because it still gives the second ValueError

Comment: Could you post the complete text of your error message?

Comment: I spotted another possible error, why is `t` empty in your code? `t` must have the same dimension as `x` in order to plot.

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict the second operand `g` to the same shape of `f`: `x = f-g[:,:11944]` or `x = f-g[:,:f.shape[1]]` also you must set `t` to have the same first dimension of `x`, try this:

```
t = np.arange(f.shape[0]*f.shape[1]).reshape(f.shape)
plt.plot(t,x) #this operation will take a long time!
```